# Size of C drive

Tags: windows, embedded

I am currently working on Windows Embedded Standard 7E on 32GB SSD.There are two partition C & D.The problem is when I check the properties of C drive it shows the space used as 3GB.But when I copy all folders inside & check the size,It shows space used as 5.32GB.I am not able to figure out what is the problem.Please help me regarding the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a filesystem feature called Symbolic Links.

A number of Windows files are duplicated across locations, typically you will see a number of files that are the same in `WinSxS` and `System32` amongst others. Rather than duplicating the entire file the filesystem can create a second link to the file data and thus use only slightly more space.

Effectively it uses only the space of one file for two copies.

By copying the files yourself it is fully duplicating the files (copy operation ignores symbolic links) and so expanding out the symbolic links is taking up more space.

Comment: So which size should i consider C drive or the folders inside the drive??

Comment: @sarang only trust the values you see in the drive properties in the chart. Windows queries those data from the NTFS metadata. They are correct.

Answer (score 0):

First, your OS may be using compression and files are uncompressed during copying.

Secondly, recent versions of Windows use a lot of symlinks and junctions. Some files are in one physical location, but appear in few different locations in the filesystem. When you're attempting to copy them, you're creating multiple physical copies instead of junctions.